# Convert .pages to .docx or .pdf using Java

Tags: java, pdf, ms-office

Is there any solution to convert .pages (Apple Pages) to .docx or .pdf files using Java? There are numerous online converters, but I would like to develop my own solution, since we have to integrate this component in another software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact solution for you, but a workaround;

1. Rename the filename.pages to filename.zip
2. Unzip the file
3. Search the contents to find the PDF version
4. Open the PDF (Now you have the PDF)
5. Use some library like  [Aspose.PDF for Java](https://blog.aspose.com/2020/01/17/convert-pdf-to-word-doc-docx-in-java/) to convert pdf to docx

Answer (score 0):

You may either use an API such [ConvertAPI](https://www.convertapi.com/pages-to-pdf) or develop an [applescript](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251333833?answerId=252585204022#252585204022) and execute it from your Java program. Sample code:

```
((new ScriptEngineManager()).getEngineByName("AppleScript")).eval(scriptString)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few Windows editors that can open Proprietary Apple.pages and just like Microsoft.docx there are dozens of variants. But they are all commonly zip archives, just like Open Office can handle. Most will contain a thumbnail preview [image]

that should be very easy to extract with TAR.

The easiest solution **is always to ask** an Apple iOSs **user** app to convert/export to Doc(x).

The next best option is to use an Apple based online converter such as iWork/iCloud or JumpShare. However you asked for an offline solution.

**Libre Office should be** able to do many parts of the zip contents XML conversion for you, and that can be driven via a command line from a shell from within MS-Office or Java Etc.

To extract some few lines of raw xml content may be easy for a small page but full conversion into ODF.XML is not trivial. Once you have a DocX conversion to PDF is then trivial such as using print to PDF via WordPad or MS/Libre Office etc.